# When I press the curly braces key on the keyboard I get a backtick instead

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

I was coding, and something happend and the curly braces key is now the backtick, and the closing curly bracket is this letter "ç", all the other special characters seem to be ok....I wasn't messing with any configuration, just using VS CODE editor and chrome.

My version of windows 10 only support one language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me your keyboard has a *US* layout (with braces to the right of the letter **P**), but the layout used by Windows switched to *Canadian French* or something similar, where those two keys are **`** and **ç**.

Did you accidentally press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>? This changes the keyboard layout used by Windows. Even though Windows uses a single language, it will still support several types of keyboard, for instance *US*, *US-International* and maybe also some country specific keyboard that has special characters such as ç. Press the same key combination to cycle through all selected layouts.

Note that in the bottom right corner there is an indicator showing the current language (For me: *NLD*). Hovering your mouse over the indicator will open a popup with information about the selected keyboard layout.

[image: Language indicator on tray]

You can also click on that same indicator to switch keyboard layouts, or open the language preferences screen. Here, you can remove unused keyboard layouts if you want.